# Um menu para cada página

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

## Problema:

O menu lateral aparece em todas as páginas.
Gostaria de poder usar um menu lateral diferente para cada página.

Sei que isso tem relação com o tema do Wordpress. Sou meio novato com o Wordpress. Eu to usando um tema padrão daqueles que já vem instalado.

## Pergunta:

Seria possível eu fazer isso que falei? Colocar um menu lateral diferente em cada página?
Se sim poderiam me passar links ou pequenas informações de como deve ser feito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível, mas para poder ajudar primeiro preciso saber o que é e como está sendo chamado esse menu lateral. Como a lateral do seu site é chamada? Normalmente existe um arquivo chamado `sidebar.php` no tema que é responsável pela apresentação das informações na lateral, se for este o caso você pode usar as funçãos `is_*();` do WordPress para checar qual página está sendo acessada e chamar o menu correto, exemplo:

Se você quiser um menu para a home e outro para todas as páginas internas:

```
if( is_home() ){
     // código do menu da home
}
else{
     // código do menu das internas
}
```

Se você quiser um menu para a home, outro para todas as internas e um diferente para a página de contato, faz assim:

```
if( is_home() ){
     // código do menu da home
}
else if( is_page( 'contato' ) ){
     // código do menu da página de contato
}
else{
     // código do menu de todas as outras páginas
}
```

Percebe que é bem relativo?

Comment: Obrigado amigo, eu tive que me ausentar por alguns dias então ainda não pude testar muitas coisas. Amanha devo ter um tempo para brincar um pouco...

Comment: Eu tenho o menu principal no topo da página com 7 links principais. Cada link principal desse deve ter um menu diferente na sidebar dentro da página. Eu fiz todos os menus dessas páginas. Botei o menu que deve aparecer na pagina 1 na sidebar, quando vou colocar o menu que deve aparecer na pagina 2 o menu da página 1 some pra aparecer o da página 2 e esse menu aparece em todas as páginas. Desculpe mas sou novo no wordpress, preciso fazer um template diferente pra cada página? Até agora o que consegui fazer foi areas de widgets diferentes.